# Incompatible key type Schema.SObjectField for Map

Tags: apex

Having the error in the title and cant see whats wrong at all:

```
Map<String, List<Contact>> taskContactsMap = new Map<String, List<Contact>>{};
for(TaskRelation tr : taskRels)
{
    List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>{};
    for(Contact contact : contacts)
    {
        if(contact.Id == tr.RelationId)
        {
            contactList.add(contact);
        }
    }

    taskContactsMap.put(tr.TaskId, contactList);
}

for(Task item : tasks)
{
    DealActivityData activityData = new DealActivityData(item, taskContactsMap.get(task.Id));

    config.addItem(new DealActivity(activityData, currentMapping), item.IsClosed);  
}
```

Its pretty simple. Making an array of Contacts and trying to put them in a map with the Task Id as the key. When I compile though I get

```
Incompatible key type Schema.SObjectField for Map<String, List<Contact>>
```

Its the taskContactsMap.get(task.Id) line thats causing the issue

Comment: Is it this line causing the problem? `taskContactsMap.put(tr.TaskId, contactList);`
If so, double check that `tr.TaskId` is indeed an `Id`. It looks like is should be, but the error is indicating otherwise.

Comment: No its the taskContactsMap.get(task.Id). Ill update the post

Comment: Can you split it out to `List<Contact> contacts = taskContactsMap.get(task.Id);`? Looks like it should work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
DealActivityData activityData = new DealActivityData(item, taskContactsMap.get(task.Id));
```

to:

```
DealActivityData activityData = new DealActivityData(item, taskContactsMap.get(item.Id));
```

The for loop is using `item` rather than `task` as the loop variable.

It's complaining about `Schema.SObjectField` as Task.Id is getting metadata for the Id field on Task. E.g. `System.debug(Task.Id);`

Comment: Cheers. Christ, silly to miss that, ill blame it on it being the end of the day. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Took it a few goes to spot it :)